# How to create a listoffigures-like heading?

Tags: sectioning, chapters

There are many commands which create a special type of heading like `\listoftables`, `\listoffigures`, `\printbibliography`, `\printglossary` et cetera. I am using the document class `report` and would like to create such a heading.

I tried:

1. `\chapter{}` but it includes `Chapter n`
2. `\chapter*{}` but it has different spacing

How can I properly imitate the heading of these commands?

I am also using this to change the sizing around the headings:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
   {\bfseries\Huge}
   {\filright\Large\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
   {0mm}{\filright}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
   {0pt}{-10pt}{15pt}
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't change my comment above. You have adjusted the setting of chapter headings but `\listoffigures` still uses `\chapter*` and so uses the setting you have specified. If you copy the definition in the 2nd comment to a `\listoffoo` command then `\listoffoo`, and `\listoffigures` will match, and will match `\chapter*`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Also if you'd copy-paste your comments into an answer I could accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `report` `\listoffigures` is defined by

```
\newcommand\listoffigures{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listfigurename}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
```

so you can copy this to a `\listoffoo` jut replacing `\listfigurename`  by `List of whatever`  and replacing `lof` by the file extension.